# How to convert audio and copy video correctly?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, aac

I have an .mp4 video file which contains a High Level 3.1 "avc1.64001f" video and a Low-Complexity AAC "mp4a.40.2" audio.

How can I convert the Low-Complexity AAC to "HE-AAC" audiocodec by using the "libfdk_aac" FFmpeg encoder and keep/get the best possible quality?
I just want to copy the "avc1.64001f" video into the target file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he out.mp4
```

The above will usually default to 48kbps per channel. Add `-vbr N` for variable bitrate mode where N can be 1-5, with 5 being the best. Or `-b:a R` e.g. `-b:a 128k` for constant bitrate mode.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is exactly what I need.